# How to pass argument to WP_Query for filtering in pre_get_posts?

Tags: filter, wordpress

I need to pass argument to WP_Query for filtering in pre_get_posts. Can you tell me why my source not works?

```
function yo_pre_get_posts( $query ){
  if( $query->get( 'yo_custom_var' ) == 'foobar' )
{
    global $wpdb; 
    $request = 'a';
    $offset = 0;
    if( isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['page']) ){
    $offset =  ($_GET['page']-1) * 100;
}

     $query = $wpdb->get_results("
            SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
            WHERE post_title LIKE '$request%'
            AND post_type = 'artist'
            AND post_status = 'publish'
            LIMIT 100 OFFSET $offset;
            ");

return $query;     }  
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'yo_pre_get_posts', 10 );
```

WP_Query

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
  ...
  'yo_custom_var' => 'foobar',
  ...
) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in the past.
in my case, i solved moving the `global $wpdb;` outside the loop.